# MySQL - #1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'components' with multiple inner joins

Tags: mysql

I have this query and I am getting error **#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'components'**. What seems to be the issue?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `products`, `components`, `tradeNames` 
INNER JOIN `componentsMap` ON componentsMap.product_id = product.id 
INNER JOIN `components` ON componentsMap.component_id = components.id 
INNER JOIN `tradeNamesMap` ON .tradeNamesMap.product_id = products.id 
INNER JOIN `tradeNames` ON tradeNamesMap.tradeName_id = tradeNames.id 
WHERE (((((LOWER(inci) LIKE '%abies%') 
          OR (trade_name.LOWER(name) LIKE '%abies%')) 
         OR (components.LOWER(no_cas)='abies')) 
        OR (components.LOWER(no_einecs)='abies')) 
       OR (components.LOWER(name)='abies'))
AND (`published`=1) 
ORDER BY `trade_name`.`name` DESC
```

Comment: Are you using a case-sensitive collation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to list the tables before the `INNER JOIN`s.  In fact, simply don't ever use commas in the `FROM` clause.  So:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `products`
INNER JOIN `componentsMap` ON componentsMap.product_id = product.id 
INNER JOIN `components` ON componentsMap.component_id = components.id 
INNER JOIN `tradeNamesMap` ON tradeNamesMap.product_id = products.id 
INNER JOIN `tradeNames` ON tradeNamesMap.tradeName_id = tradeNames.id 
WHERE (((((LOWER(inci) LIKE '%abies%') 
          OR (trade_name.LOWER(name) LIKE '%abies%')) 
         OR (components.LOWER(no_cas)='abies')) 
        OR (components.LOWER(no_einecs)='abies')) 
       OR (components.LOWER(name)='abies'))
AND (`published`=1) 
ORDER BY `trade_name`.`name` DESC;
```

The above query only returns one row because of the `COUNT()`.  The `order by` suggests that you actually want this information for each `trade_name.name`.  If so, you need a `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT tn.name, COUNT(*)
FROM `products` p INNER JOIN
     `componentsMap cm
     ON cm.product_id = p.id INNER JOIN
     `components` c
     ON cm.component_id = c.id INNER JOIN
     `tradeNamesMap` tnm
     ON tnm.product_id = p.id INNER JOIN
     `tradeNames` tn
     ON tnm.tradeName_id = tn.id 
WHERE ((LOWER(inci) LIKE '%abies%') OR
       (tn.LOWER(name) LIKE '%abies%') OR
       (c.LOWER(no_cas)='abies') OR
       (c.LOWER(no_einecs)='abies') OR
       (c.LOWER(name)='abies')
      ) AND
      (`published` = 1) 
GROUP BY tn.name
ORDER BY tn.`name` DESC
```

Comment: I see an ugly dot in the INNER JOIN tradeNamesMap` ON **.** as well

Comment: It is working :). Thanks for the extensive answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
INNER JOIN `[components]` ON componentsMap.component_id = components.id
```

AND

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `products`, [`components`], `tradeNames`
```

Two `components` are there.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing, and untested, but I suspect that something like this would do what you're after...

```
SELECT n.name
     , COUNT(*)
  FROM products p
  JOIN componentsMap pc
    ON pc.product_id = p.id 
  JOIN components c
    ON c.id = pc.component_id 
  JOIN tradeNamesMap pn
    ON pn.product_id = p.id 
  JOIN tradeNames n
    ON n.id = pn.tradeName_id 
 WHERE 
     ( inci LIKE '%abies%'
    OR n.name LIKE '%abies%'
    OR 'abies' IN (c.no_cas,c.no_einecs,c.name)
     )
   AND published = 1
 GROUP
    BY n.name
 ORDER 
    BY n.name DESC
```